# Node JS fetch POST won't res.render a pug

Tags: node.js, post, fetch, render

So I've been stuck on this for a while, I think it might have something to do with content-type but I'm not sure, I'll leave that up to you all.

**script.js**

```
let pass = {username: username, password: password};

fetch("/login",{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(pass)
}).catch(function (err) {
    alert("Something's wrong :(");
});
```

**server.js**

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render('main',{
        username: 'aaaaaa',
        favorites: ''
    });
});
```

If I try to change the content-type then the body comes back empty and the render still doesn't do anything.

If I run a regular GET request from index.html (not using fetch) it runs the render as expected. Just need to use the post one to pass data to the pug.

```
app.get('/createUser', function (req, res){
    res.render('main',{
        username: 'aaaaaa',
        favorites: ''
    });
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/' + 'public/createUser.html');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Also tried using middle ware and sessions below, same result. Would not render page. Not sure how to change from a post to get request if that's what I need to do.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'tarter sauce',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
    }))

app.post('/login', log, test, main);



function log(req, res, next) {
    //console.log(req);
    req.session.valid = false;
    console.log(req.body);
    const input = req.body;
    console.log(input);
    console.log(input.username);
    fs.readFile('users.json', (err,data)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        const users = JSON.parse(data);
        //console.log("data "+data);
        //console.log(req.headers['content-type']);
        if (users.hasOwnProperty(input.username)){
            //console.log("is a user");
            if(users[input.username].password==input.password){
                //console.log("login success");
                const response = {
                    username: users[input.username].username,
                    favorites: users[input.username].favorites
                };
                req.session.username = users[input.username].username;
                req.session.favorites = users[input.username].favorites;
                req.session.valid = true;
            }
        }
        //console.log("next");
        next();
    });
}

function test(req, res, next){
    //console.log("test");
    next();
}

function main(req, res){
    //console.log(req.session.username);
    //console.log("render");
    res.send();
    res.render('main', {
        username: "req.session.username",
        favorites: "req.session.favorites"
    });
    res.end;
};
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you set `app.set('view engine', 'pug')`? Is the pug file in the correct place?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to include that part, yes I have set that and the file is in the correct place. When I run an empty get request directly from index.html the res.render works. I'll add these things to the question. No error message is given.

Comment: If body-parser is included in your server.js then req.body will be automatically parsed into a JavaScript object when your route is called with content-type = "application/json", so you're doing that right.

Comment: In your GET route, why are you using res.sendFile?  That should give you an error saying something about sending a response after one has already been sent.  Is the res.render not working in the GET?

Comment: Why are you trying to render a response to a POST? That's an anti-pattern. POST sends _to_ the server and the typical response is status + JSON. If you want your server to render a page after the POST, your `app.post('/login'` route should instead use a `res.redirect` (instead of render) to one of your GET routes.

Comment: And to clarify on my previous - if your POST is not sending data back you can res.redirect to a GET route. Otherwise your client side code should process the response and then redirect from the client to a GET route, where you can render a response. POST does not render a response in the paradigm you presented.

Comment: @Chase could you show me how I would set up the redirect to pass the data (username and favorites) over to the get?

Comment: You want to look into sessions. Store the vars from your POST in a session. Then you access the session when the client makes the followup GET. I'm assuming you're using Express, which means sessions come via middleware. [Express Session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) is what you want.

Comment: @chase ok I looked into middlewares and sessions and I've been able to use some of it but still seem to run into the same problem. The issue is I have to use a post for the original data because it contains passwords, but I don't know how to change to a get request and have to run 'main' as a function. I updated the code above.

Comment: I'd like to help but it sounds like the issue is a little bigger than just a couple functions. You should consider taking a step back and learning more about the authentication paradigm in web apps and how that flows back and forth between client and server. Find a tutorial that builds a basic site login and start from there. You need a good understanding of how these pieces work before you try and implement them together. It's not difficult, you can learn it in a couple days. Good luck.